# Is there a way to Rotate Map Window or Layout in MapInfo Pro v16?

Tags: mapinfo, layouts

I have a town that is long and narrow on a north-west aligned coast. Ideally I would like to print a properties and water network for the town at around a 1:5000 or greater scale, with the map realigned to have the town lie lengthways.

Have only been using MapInfo for a few months, coming from an ESRI background where this task is pretty straight forward. It looks like there was a tool in previous 32-bit versions of MapInfo to rotate the Map window, but it does not appear to have made into the new 64-bit versions of MapInfo.

I don't have the necessary programming skills to even begin to construct my own tool to do this. Hopefully I have simply overlooked a MapInfo Pro feature or someone can point me in the right direction to a community made tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventough we haven't brought the Rotate Map Window tool into 64 bit, it still works in the 64 bit release of MapInfo Pro. I have tested the tool from MapInfo Pro 15.0 in MapInfo Pro 16.0.

I have shared the tool here: [Rotate Map Window](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1a4tpb06ahg1fjt/RotateMapWindow.zip?dl=1).
This means that you don't have to download the MapInfo Pro 15.0 trial to get the tool.

1. Run the tool using Ctrl+U which will load it into the Tools Window. In the Tools window select the tool and right click it to get to it's context menu.
2. Select the menu item *Rotate Map Window*.
3. Click the button Map Center to make the tool rotate the window around the center.
4. Enter a rotation angle or use one of the fixed rotation value buttons

Comment: Perfect. Just what I needed.

Comment: The link where Peter Horsboll Moller has shared the tool is no longer working. Is there an alternative link? or is there a command that can be used in the mapbasic window?

Comment: @stephanie, I have  updated the link so that it now again should work.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Rotate Map Window comes with MapInfo Pro v19